# CSS is styling incorrect element only in Safari

Tags: css, sass, safari, laravel-mix

So having a really weird issue here, only in Safari 13.0.5, tested on multiple machines and get the same error.

The project itself is a networking app built with Laravel, using Laravel Mix to compile assets.

I have a form with an ID of `profileForm`:

```
<form id="profileForm">
... inputs
</form>
```

This form uses the default form styling I've created for this project - which is working fine.

However the weird thing is, some styles from inside a media query from a **completely separate element** are being applied here?

```
.profile-modal {
      .. other styles
      @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        padding-left: 70px !important;
        padding-right: 70px !important;
      }
    }
```

This form does not have the `.profile-modal` class, yet Safari is applying the above styling to it which is for a completely separate part of the website.

If I rename the class in the sass to something completely random, i.e:

```
.asdfghjkl {
          .. other styles
          @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            padding-left: 70px !important;
            padding-right: 70px !important;
          }
        }
```

It still applies those styles to this element as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cop4Z.png)

To combat this, I thought as a temporary measure I could add the following to my blade template to remove the padding:

```
<style>
    .profile-modal{
        padding-left: initial !important;
        padding-right: initial !important;
    }
</style>
```

However that didn't apply to the broken element, to get it to work I have to use the correct ID `#profileForm`.

Has anyone else had this issue on the latest version of Safari?